# SSRS Charts: solution for better assignment of colors to the legend

Tags: reporting-services, charts

If you have a line chart in SSRS with many lines, it is nearly impossible to identify which line belongs to which item in the legend, as the colors are nearly the same. Is there a better solution?

[bad example of line chart legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnE81.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions that may help:

- Group some of the values into an *Other* group. It looks like you have
  some values that come and go, or don't run for the full timeframe of the
  report, lumping these into an *Other* group will mean less legend items.
- Move the legend to the bottom of the chart. This can sometimes make
  the legend easier to see; this is not a good option when have a lot
  more legend items than what you have now.
- Use more than one chart; one chart for each line is possible. This
  may be a good option for you. Use more than one chart, and only
  display certain values in each. Perhaps you have some natural
  grouping in the data that isn’t obvious from what you have provided
  in the question. If you do, use that to separate the values into
  different charts.
- Use a different color theme. The theme you are using now would leave
  any color-blind person wondering what was in the chart at all.
- Make the chart larger. You just never know, this may work.
- Use a column chart rather than a line chart. The bars are wider, and
  can be easier to see. Plus, with the way your values come and go, it
  may be a better way to visualize the data.
- Limit the timeframe of the data being displayed. Having less data may
  make this look better, but that may defeat the purpose of the report.
  Still, it’s an option.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

All good ideas by R Richards. I often end up with charts looking like yours. The first thing I do is ask. Is this of any use to the end user, if not I'll try to rationalise the chart. Some of the ideas in the earlier answer are things I try but also you can try the following without reducing the amount of data in the chart.

1. Simply make the lines thicker, it's much easier to identify the colours with thicker lines.
2. Add tooltips to the data points so that the user can hover over the
   lines and get info about the line and/or point.
3. Use a custom pallet, the default palette does not have many colours in (7 I think), so colours are repeated. Creating a custom palette with more colours will make it easier to identify each line. It also means, if you can ensure the order of series in your data that you can you produce consistent charts were a colour always represents a specific business object.
4. If you have breaks in the data, change the chart to use an average
   to give you a continuous line. I think your x axis has to be set as
   a time type for this to work, I can't remember off the top of my
   head.

Here's a before and after the first two ideas were applied to a sample chart I built.

[image: Before]

[image: After thickening lines and adding tooptip]

If you think you need to reduce the data, group line with smaller values together and then add a drill down chart to show these lines.